# My icom IC 735 has no TX, external meter shows correct amount of power but no one can hear me

Tags: transceiver

I pulled apart to get to the pa board and checked the three amp fuse it was fine. All I could find on the main board was diodes D33 and D34 were cut but I learned that was from the Mars mod. Im Stumped!  I'm not great with circuits. I don't see anything visibly wrong. Anyone know what could be the issue or what I need to test? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked mic gain ?

Comment: And are you sure they are listening on the frequency you are transmitting on? Your frequency might have shifted causing you to transmit on another nearby frequency.

Comment: What mode are you in?

Comment: Ssb or am. Now it's not showing any output on the meter at all.

Comment: Ssb or am.  Same either way.  Now it's showing no output.

Comment: Yes, I checked mic. Gain

Comment: Yes, I'm sure they were listening on correct frequency.  An Elmer explained to me my icom has a pll. Phase locked loop and of it shifted frequency I would definitely know. I think he said the display would only out I believe